# Compare two Address Registers in Motorolla 68k

Tags: assembly, branch, memory-address, motorola, 68000

I have a simple program, where I'm trying to understand how to compare two address registers, and branch if A1 is less than or equal to A2

As such:

```
    ORG    $8000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

    CMP A2,A1
    BLE LOOP ;if A1 is less then or equal to A2, BRANCH

LOOP: 

* Put variables and constants here

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? What if I used the macro `CMPA`here instead, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `cmpa` to compare with an addressregister on 68K. You don't have a choice.

Also it's best to include the size suffix **.L** to make sure the full 32 bits are compared as opposed to a sign-extended version of the low 16 bits.

```
CMPA.L A2,A1
BLE.S  LOOP
```

Comment: Doesn't the assembly language automatically convert CMP appropriately, for you though?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `cmp.L` for sure, since many 68k assemblers default to .w when no size is set and then you'd end up with CPU sign-extending lower 16 bit contents of addresses and then comparing them as 32-bit quantities (68k does so only for address arithmetics).

In contrary, most assemblers (at least known to me) will automatically select cmp**a** when destination of cmp is an address register.

Also, I see no reason in signed comparison of addresses with `ble`.
Unsigned comparisons are more appropriate here, for example:

```
     lea   Start,a0
     lea   Start+size,a1
loop:clr.l (a0)+
     cmp.l a0,a1
     bhi.s loop
```